# Python - SQLite - Insert values based on tuple information

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a sqlite table:

```
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
                        ID integer not null primary key,
                        Department text ,
                        Standing text ,
                        GPA real, 
                        unique(ID) 
                    );""")
```

I have a list of tuples:

```
all_info =[('MATH', 70, 10, 20), ('BIOLOGY', 82, 12, 15), ('CHEMISTRY', 78, 30, 20), ('COMPUTER SCIENCE', 113, 5, 15), ('INFORMATICS', 138, 16, 2), ('ENGLISH', 94, 17, 33), ('SPANISH', 118, 7, 42), ('BIOCHEMISTRY', 104, 14, 39),
```

The tuple contains info of the number of students for each department. For instance the Math department has 70 students in honors standing, 10 students in probation and 20 students in normal standing, for a total of 100 students.

I need to insert data into the students database based on information in the tuple. 
Desired result of student table:

```
ID    Department   Standing   GPA  
1     Math         Honors     93
2     Math         Honors     93
3     Math         Probation  60
...and so on.
(there would be 70 entries of math students in Honors standing with a GPA of 93.)
```

If the student is a honor student their GPA would be 93, if a student is on probation their GPA would be 60 if a student is in normal standing their GPA would be 80.

I am having trouble programatically inserting values into the students table based on information from the list of tuples.

Thank you.

Edit 1:
I am stuck on where to start, I have thought to loop through the list of tuples

```
for item in all_info:
    ID = randint(1,99999)
    num_honor = item[1]
    num_prob = item[2]
    num_norm = item[3]
   cur.execute(INSERT statement..)
```

But this would only enter in what is in each tuple, any ideas for inserting rows based on the number in the tuple?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet of what you have already tried

Comment: Edited, I haven't really came up with anything to try yet -- I added some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
for each_tuple in all_info:
  Department = each_tuple[0]
  students_list = [(Department, 'Honors', 93) for i in range (0, each_tuple[1])] + [(Department, 'Probation', 60) for i in range (0, each_tuple[3])]+ [(Department, 'Normal', 80) for i in range (0, each_tuple[2])]

  cur.executemany('INSERT INTO students VALUES(?,?,?);',student_list)
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to add a random number before the department string?  Thanks again!

Comment: Then you can use string formatting `f"Your random number {Department}"`